# addeventlistener not working more than once with a button

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener

The Event is triggered only for the first time the button is clicked.

```html
<button id="b">huerig</button>
<script>
  y = function(evt) {
    document.body.innerHTML += evt.type;
  }
  b = document.querySelector("#b");
  b.addEventListener("click", y);
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you concatenate a container with `innerHTML`, any Javascript references to elements inside the container are lost, as are all listeners - the container is emptied and re-parsed according to the new HTML string.

To avoid this problem, append *actual elements* instead:

```js
const y = function(evt) {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
    .textContent = evt.type;
}
const b = document.querySelector("#b");
b.addEventListener("click", y);
```

```html
<button id="b">huerig</button>
```

Or use `insertAdjacentHTML`:

```js
const y = function(evt) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', evt.type);
}
const b = document.querySelector("#b");
b.addEventListener("click", y);
```

```html
<button id="b">huerig</button>
```

(You should also try to avoid implicitly creating global variables - use `const` / `let` / `var` when creating new variables)

Answer (score 0):

`document.body.innerHTML` is removing the javascript reference and `document.body` becomes empty.Create a div and add the text inside that

```js
var b = document.querySelector("#b");
let count = 0;
let y = function(evt) {

  document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML += evt.type + count;
  count++

}
b.addEventListener("click", y);
```

```html
<button id="b">huerig</button>
<div id="text">
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you replace previous button with new button In this line:

```
document.body.innerHTML+=evt.type;
```

Use this lines in your function:

```
   var ne=document.createElement("SPAN");
   ne.innerHTML=evt.type;
   document.body.appendChild(ne);
```